# How can I limit the creation of new records to 1 record per parent record?

Tags: custom-object, record, create-records

Is there a solution to limit the creation of 1 record, per parent record?

If I disable the "new" button, is there a specific filter for this scenario?

If I should establish database control, what do you recommend?

Comment: This sounds like an X-Y problem to me. Please go into detail about what the overall problem is (the problem where a solution could be "limit to creating a single record").

Comment: I'm posting a question on stack exchange because I do not know how to limit 1 record PER object. Im not "running into errors" Im asking how to limit 1 record per object.

Comment: and I'm asking _why_ you need to limit to 1 record per object because, given the experience I have, that requirement doesn't make much sense. What is it that limiting something to having one record helps you do (aside from the obvious of only having a single record)? See also https://xyproblem.info/

Comment: @DerekF the custom object at hand is for "cancelled" contracts, in which case, there should only be 1 record at all times requesting cancellation. 1 contract, 1 cancellation request/ related record *only*; Also, the reasoning behind it is to prevent users from accidentally creating more than 1 request/record which could trigger a cascade of unwanted events

Comment: Because I think that there's more to this request than you have told us, and knowing more about the "big picture" here will almost certainly lead you to a better solution in a quicker timeframe.

Comment: Ah, that's definitely a very important detail right there. "1 child record per parent" and "1 record per object" are _very different things_. The way you initially phrased your question, I read it as "I want to create an SObject, and this SObject should only have a single record _in the entire org_".

Comment: @DerekF 1 child record per parent is correct. any input?

Answer (score 2):

A completely declarative solution to this problem without Flows would be to create a rollup field on the parent that counts the number of child records you have and add a validation rule to the child object. You can achieve this with a master-detail relationship or a custom rollup app that does this for you.

The idea is that when a child record is created and associated with the parent record, the counter on the parent record will be increased from nothing or zero to one.

Then you can create a validation rule on the child record that disallows the creation of the record if the parent's counter is greater than zero (that is: the parent already has a child record associated with it).

Comment: roll-up summary counts can only reference master detail relationships and I cannot create this type of field for specific custom object because it's exceeding the maximum # of a master-detail relationships on parent object. is there a work-around?

Comment: @ahon the workaround is the solution that I suggested.

Comment: You could create a regular lookup and use a separate tool to rollup the value (effectively mimicking the built-in feature).

Answer (score 1):

After some back-and-forth in the comments, the question here is *how do I limit a parent record so that it can only have a single child record (of a particular child SObject) that has an "open" status?*

Yes, it is possible.

There are likely multiple solutions, but I think the most straightforward here would be to use a `before insert` trigger to detect this situation and use `.addError()` to tell Salesforce to prevent the insert from completing.

In a nutshell:

- Iterate over `trigger.new` and gather the Contract Ids
- Query for the Contract records *with a subquery for child "Cancellation" records*, store in a Map with the Contract Id as the key
- Iterate over `trigger.new` again

  - `get()` the Contract from the Map
  - check to see if the subquery returned any records
  - `.addError()` if there is any existing child record

The query you'd use might look like

```
Map<Id, Contract> contractMap = new Map<Id, Contract>([
    SELECT Id, (SELECT Id FROM Cancellations__r LIMIT 1) 
    FROM Contract 
    WHERE Id IN :contractIds
]);
```

"Cancellations__r" would need to be replaced by whatever the child relationship name is (and yes, the "__r" is on purpose and correct when it's a custom relationship field and you're trying to get data on related records).

You could adjust the subquery to `(SELECT Id FROM Cancellations__r WHERE Status = 'Open' LIMIT 1)` if, for example, you want to allow another cancellation request if the first one is denied.

The `LIMIT 1` part is to keep the number of query rows to a minimum. Doing that also would make it safe to access the subquery results directly instead of using a nested loop to access them. I.e. it makes the following code "safe" where it would otherwise not be "safe"

```
if(contractMap.get(myCancellation.Contract__c).Cancellations__r.size() > 0)
```

Answer (score 0):

EDITED BASED ON COMMENTS:

This is a overly simplistic and untested way, but I suspect you could create something that would work (though certainly not the most robust way) for this with a simple custom field set to be a unique value and a record triggered flow. Assuming you want to create a single record per parent record (as suggested in comments):

1. Create a custom field (not a formula field) and make its value unique (set the "Do not allow duplicate values" checkbox to true when creating it)
2. Make the field read only for the relevant users
3. Create a record triggered flow to update the custom field to some value that identifies the parent record. For example, the id of the parent record. We'll call this parentRecordId
4. (EDIT#2: This step is not possible for RT flows, see end note.) Ensure your flow runs as "System Context Without Sharing" so that it can act on records regardless of the user's permissions (user has no permission to edit custom field)
5. Activate flow

When a new record is created, it will attempt to use parentRecordId for the new record, which will fail because you already have a record with a unique value of parentRecordId. If you need to allow a different record to be created, you can edit the existing record for the object to a different value so that a new one can be created (though that is probably a manual process that you want to avoid).

This way each child record created for a parent record will take up the "only" possible unique value available per parent record.

Of course this process doesn't allow for custom error messages, and your users would probably only see something like "Error: Duplicate Record detected" or something like that, I don't exactly recall. But it could get the job in a very simplistic way.

NOTE: RT flows cant be set to run in system context, so maybe you'd have to give the user access to edit the custom field, but not show it anywhere and make it read only at the page layout level

Comment: A declarative way to achieve this thing (just based on formula and default values) would be great - but how? E.g. formulas in field defaults don't allow a reference to the parent object. Please think this through and add a working example to your answer.

Comment: Fair point about the default values. An easy workaround is to use a record triggered flow, per updated answer. The "How" is explicitly stated in the answer (albeit updated per this discussion). As most answers on this site, mine is a suggestion to solve the problem requested, and I don't believe it needs to be a fully functional and completely, thoroughly tested method to be valuable for the user asking. Hope it's helpful for @ahon, but maybe it doesn't fit their use case.